# Various crashes caused by malloc: incorrect checksum when porting an iOS project to arm64

Tags: ios, crash, malloc, memory-alignment, arm64

We have a small amount of CPP code mixed in with a lot of C and Objective-C code.  In most cases, I'm seeing a crash when deleting a particular object.  It's not a double free, because I can step through the destructor (it's a CPP object) and once the destructor is complete, the process aborts with message...

> malloc: *** error for object 0x124ea55f8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.

The address reported in the error is always 440 bytes away (sizeof the class is 448 bytes) from the base address of the object being deleted, though even if I get rid of all deallocation code in my destructor (effectively creating a memory leak), it will still crash in the same fashion at the same address offset.

This has never occurred in the 32 bit build and the code has been stable for quite some time.  This is also only the most frequent case of this type of crash.  I've seen it occur at various random other times in regions far away from the aforementioned case, which leads me to suspect that perhaps there are misalignments causing a much more serious issue.

Are these known problems when porting to arm64 and are there tools to help in diagnosing the problems?

Comment: I'd suspect different length data structures are probably at the root of your problem and C/C++ code thinks the data structure is padded but Obj C does not, or vice versa.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  Unfortunately the codebase is enormous and I'm afraid the problem could be stemming from something further away causing misalignment.  Actually on this particular thread, the call stack never enters Obj-C code at all.  It's a case of C code deleting a CPP object.